# How to use UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadArray<T> (Int64, T[], Int32, Int32)

Tags: c#, shared-memory

I want to read/write data to Memory Mapped File .How do I use UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadArray (Int64, T[], Int32, Int32)

1. struct Data{public int a; public int b; public byte[] ;}
2. static Data _sdata = new Data();
   static Data _mydata = new Data();
   _mdata.byte = _sdata.byte = new byte[2] ;
3. _mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew( "test", 10);
4. var ired = _mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
5. ired.Read( 0, out mdata );`here has Error`
   So, what is the T struct should correct ??

Answer (score 0):

The array cannot be a reference it has to be contained within the struct. You have to enable unsafe code for your assembly and use the following struct definition :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
unsafe struct Data {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public fixed byte bytes[100];
}
```